# Visual Studio pending changes window like ANKHSVN with GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

Is there an extension for GIT that has the pending changes window like ANKHSVN's?

GIT Extensions and GIT Source Control Provider both have the window but you cannot open the file in VS like you can with ANKHSVN it just does the compare right in the window (unless i'm missing a setting somewhere).

To sum up i'm looking for a GIT pending changes window that when I double click or hit the enter key when the file is selected it opens it in edit inside VS.

Edit: I'm asking about the "Pending Changes" window not the solution explorer filter.

Comment: Did you click on the "Compare" option in the context menu? Perhaps you should change your title to "How can I change the double-click behaviour in the Changes window of the GIT Source Control Provider" or something similar?

Comment: Isn't this what it does today?  If I open the Changes hub, then double click a file, it will open in the editor.  If I right-click, I can choose Compare to unmodified.

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm I'm talking about the "Pending Changes" window not the solution explorer pending changes filter. I will update my question with that info.

Comment: @Josh "Pending Changes" is a TFS window that only works when you use TFS. What you are talking about is exactly what Terje mentions - the Changes hub in the Team Explorer window. Not the filter in Solution Explorer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ankhsvn/screenshots and look at the pending changes window. Am I misinformed as to what that is called?

Comment: Yes. Different tools, diffent windows. What you are looking for is the Changes hub in Team Explorer

Comment: Ok so then do you know of an extension for GIT that acts similar? Also what should I update my question to to reflect that window i'm talking about?

Comment: What *are* you talking about? How to change the behaviour of double clicking in the Changes window? How to change the name from Changes to an incorrect one - "Pending Changes"?  Because the changes aren't pending, they've already been made. They haven't been commited locally or pushed to any remote repositor*ies*. There's no central server in Git so "pending changes" has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Execute "gitk" in the terminal. This will open up a GUI to track local uncommitted changes in the index.